# How to avoid duplicating ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller Actions returning View/PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action, partial-views

I have a bunch of controller actions that return a View. Now I need to also return PartialView for each action because I want to make my assembly reusable in a parent application with parent views (I will use Html.Action in the parent View). It's a bit cumbersome to duplicate each action to return a partial view. Isn't there a cleaner way to disable the layout when nesting a controller action inside a parent view?

Answer (score 2):

You can check `ControllerContext.IsChildAction` in your action method and return a different view if it is true.

```
if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
{
    return PartialView("_Index", model)
}
else 
{
    return View("Index", model)
}
```

If it makes sense for your application, load the partial view in your full view so that you can reuse the markup.

Comment: Oh that's really nice! So I could make a special Controller base class and add a PossiblePartialView(string view, object model) method to it that does this. I'll try that out.